# How can I Set Grid Layout gravity using kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout

I tried using setGravity, but not sure how it's supposed to work.

Kotlin :

```
private fun sizefix(view : View)
{
  val gridlyt : GridLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.gridlayout)
  val param = GridLayout.LayoutParams()
  param.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER)
  gridlyt.layoutParams = param
}
```

XML :

```
<GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/gridlayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:columnCount="5"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp">
```

Doing this causes a crash

Comment: Isn't there [`LayoutParams.setGravity(gravity: Int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/widget/GridLayout.LayoutParams#setGravity(kotlin.Int))?

Comment: Can you post your XML layout and grid layout initialization code?